# Introduce a box with special symbols in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, symbols

I want to have a gnuplot with a box on the right top corner like the one below. My difficulties are both:

1. how to get \hat{Q} in a the legend?
2. how to add a box containing the titles?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set term cairolatex eps standalone size 3in,3in
set output 'Q.tex'
set key box opaque samplen 0.5
plot for [i=1:4] sinc(x)**i title sprintf('\tiny${\hat{Q}=%d}$',i) lw 2
```

The `standalone` keyword wraps the output in minimal LaTeX commands so that you can run `latex Q` directly.  Omit this if you want to produce a LaTeX fragment for including in a larger document.

I show how to construct a formatted title that includes a LaTeX font size. Note that the format uses single quotes rather than double quotes.

This example uses `cairolatex eps` because you specifically asked about an eps file.  Normallay I would use `cairolatex png` or `cairolatex pdf` and process afterwards with `pdflatex` rather than plain `latex`.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your effort. However, I do not obtain the same than you: the box in the top right only contains the colors but not the Q legends, the plot itself appears squeezed and the axes are not numbered. It seems obvious that something happens with the compiler. What could it be?

Comment: It really sounds like you are not processing the gnuplot output through latex. Gnuplot outputs two files: FILE.tex is a latex script; FILE.eps is a graphics-only fragment for inclusion in the latex document. Running `latex FILE` combines these two to make a new file FILE.dvi that contains a latex figure including both text and graphics. To further convert this dvi latex output back into PostScript (if that's what you want) you need an additional step using a conversion utility. For example `dvips FILE.dvi -o MYFIGURE.ps`

Comment: That is right. It worked by compiling the .tex file obtained through Gummi (as perhaps would happen with any other tex compiler). Thank you for helping up to the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include your figure into LaTeX, you should use the terminal `cairolatex`, then you can include LaTeX code in your plots:

`plot "your.data" title '$\hat{Q}=10$'`

Concerning your second question, have a look at the manual concerning `set key`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and rapid response. However, I cannot get an .eps file by using cairolatex instead of postscript, the terminal I was using. Is there a way to have a title '$\hat{Q}=10$' using the postscript terminal on Gnuplot?

Comment: cairolatex does not produce .eps, but .tex and .pdf instead. If you need to have .eps, you can also use epslatex. You might need to adapt your options in the `set term ...` line, best thing would be to look into the manual (it's very well written!)

Comment: Thank you again. I solved it just typing 'set output' after calling to plot the data. Now it draws the function but the title does not appear at all...